# Javascript Limit show image into 1 display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm currently working on displaying an image using Javascript and Jquery which I will use for another project luckily there are many resources in the web, and I can now display an image however, once the user clicks the button again it will display another image, I'm trying to limit the display into 1 only. How can I achieve this?any comment/suggestions/opinion is appreciated.

Here's my code and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/1560/

html

```
 <select name="code" id="code" size="">
        <option value="">imgA</option>
        <option value="">imgB</option>
        <option value="">imgC</option>
        <option value="">imgD</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="showimg()" value="Display">
```

javascript

```
function showimg() {
        var q = document.getElementById("code");
        var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;

        var src = "img/"+selected+".png"; 
        show_image(src);
}
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = 100;
        img.height=100;
        img.alt=alt;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `appendChild`, simply set the `src` of an existing img tag. Otherwise you would need to remove the old image from the DOM before your `appendChild` call.

**HTML**

```
<select name="code" id="code" size="">
        <option value="">imgA</option>
        <option value="">imgB</option>
        <option value="">imgC</option>
        <option value="">imgD</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="showimg()" value="Display">
<img src="placeholder.png" id="placeholderImg" style="display: none;" />
```

**JS**

```
function showimg() {
    var q = document.getElementById("code");
    var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;

    var src = "http://www.unc.edu/~matusiak/imgs/Under-Construction-1.gif";
    var img = document.getElementById("placeholderImg");
    img.src = src;
    img.style.display = "inline";
}
```

Here is an [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25ecg/2/).

Additionally, there is **no jQuery here**. If you are using jQuery, you should replace your function with:

```
$(function() {
    $("input").click(function() {
        var selected = $("#code").val();
        $("#placeholderImg").attr("src", "http://www.unc.edu/~matusiak/imgs/Under-Construction-1.gif");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your code like it is just add a boolean `var display = false;` then set it to `true` when image is displayed

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/1561/)

```
var display =  false;
function showimg() {
        var q = document.getElementById("code");
        var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;

        var src = "http://www.unc.edu/~matusiak/imgs/Under-Construction-1.gif";
        if(!display){ //test if image has already been displayed
            show_image(src);
            display =  true;
        }
}
```